# It is planned in Dart language adding functionality to declaring closures (without using typedef) as typed functions?

Tags: dart

Closures in Dart language used very often because they very powerful.

I want ask question about closures usability.

Assume this source code:

```dart
class SomeWork<T> {
  Function _test;

  SomeWork(bool test(T a, T b)) {
    _test = test;
  }
}
```

If I rewrote this code as this code fragment then the function (as an argument) will be untyped (or rather will have a different type).

```dart
class SomeWork<T> {
  final Function test;

  SomeWork(this.test) {
  }
}
```

Question:

- It is planned in Dart language adding functionality to declaring closures (without using typedef, "on the fly") as typed functions?

Like this example of code:

```dart
class SomeWork<T> {
  final Function<bool, T, T> test;

  SomeWork(this.test) {
  }
}
```

---

P.S.

For clarification I want add (after a while) this example in C# language because as I understand given example in the Dart language perceived not entirely correct.

```cs
class SomeWork<T> {
  sealed Func<T, T, bool> m_test;
  SomeWork(Func<T, T, bool> test)
  {             
    m_test = test;        
  }
}
```

I.e. I asked about about possibility using types similar to C# `Func<>` and `Action<>`.

Comment: I think it is better to ask questions on language design on the Dart mailing list. StackOverflow is better suited to 'how-to' questions.

Comment: I can only get the down votes for this question from those who are comfortable with the fact that there is. I wanted as the best but turned out as always. I do not infringe on the sanctity of Dart, do not need me voting down for this question.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no plans here that I know of. Early in Dart's development, there were a number of discussions about this unfortunate corner of the type annotation syntax, but the language designers feel it's a worthwhile trade-off in order to have type annotations that look familiar to programmers coming from C, C++, Java, and C#.

Comment: I not understand what you mean when mentioned about `familiarity` with C# language in relation to Dart.
My question and the last example based on the `similarity` with C#. One `difference` are that in `C# this is possible` but in Dart not. In C# this can be declared like this type `Func<T, T, bool>`. This kind of `type specification` can be used `anywhere`. Even for declaring type `function parameters`. Sorry, but where you found something that not as in C# I don't understand.

Comment: You're right that we could use a syntax like `Fn<R, A>` for function types like C#, but previous discussions about function type usually used a more readable custom syntax like `A => R` like other languages use.

Comment: Please give me the real example of using `A => R` for declaring type of `final` variable with parameterized `Function` type.